# How can I update the description of a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When I create a Lightning Component I'm prompted for the `Name` and `Description`.

Later, I may want to change the `Description`, but how can I do this? I do not see a way to edit it from Developer Console.

I did try using MavensMate + SublimeText to edit the `MyComponent.cmp-meta.xml` but when I saved the file I get error `[ERROR]: Could not update lightning components: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined`.

**MyComponent.cmp-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AuraDefinitionBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>38.0</apiVersion>
    <description>How to update this description?</description>
</AuraDefinitionBundle>
```

Comment: Did you tried clean project in the Mavesnmate project and try changing description

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, yes, I also tried uploading the package metadata to Workbench and the description still didn't change.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with Mavensmate .If you ANT installed in your machine or Force.com CLI ,its possible to update description but sounds so silly now that this is not possible to edit

Comment: @MohithShrivastava yeah, silly it's not editable from UI. I was able to get this to work using Force.com IDE per John's answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to directly edit and save the *.cmp-meta.xml file using Eclipse (version 4.6.0) with the Force.com plugin (version 37.0.0.201609220436). After saving the file I logged into my (Sandbox) Org and was able to see the new description.

(I couldn't find a way to edit from Dev Console either...)

Comment: Thanks John! Using Eclipse Force.com plugin did allow me to edit the component description in the *.cmp-meta.xml file then I did a deployment to server.

Answer (score 6):

Btw. I know this question is a bit older but maybe someone needs this again and I think the following way is much faster.

Just make a query within the Dev. Console of Salesforce and change the Description.

```
Select Id, DeveloperName, Description from AuraDefinitionBundle
```

Comment: This worked for me!